# How can I use sendkeys for this kind of details?

Tags: java, android, appium

In my case I have SignUp page and it consists 2 fields. One is country code and another is Phone number field. After inspecting with UI Automator 
found that

1. Node details for country code field is

[image]

2. Node details for Phone number field is

[image]

> NOTE: **the page doesn't have any xpath for those elements**

Now how do I enter phone number in Phone number field? Because
both the field consists same class and same index value and phone number field doesn't have any name assigned to it.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. `X-Path` would differ surely for both of them. Try using it.
2. Password could be accessed using the `ID` (hidden in the question)
3. `Index` are used to access elements once you get a `list` of identical elements, which for you is not the case.

Comment: i know using xpaths but the page doesn't have xpaths.

Comment: @Prateek.Naik : both the NATIVE and WEBVIEW contexts have x-paths, probably you are just ending up not finding them.

Comment: as i said there are no xpaths (inspected form UI automator tool). May be because of google new material design, the xpath is not available. So my question here again is, how do i tap on the fields?.

Comment: One thing i want to ask the people(those who down voted), can you people tell me why it has been down voted? is there anything wrong in the question?. Please tell me the reason so that i can correct it or may be i can delete the post.

Comment: @Prateek.Naik : you can use to Appium Inspector to find the value of xpath of an element. Also there is no hierarchy where you can say **there are no xpath**. Please try and look for the details by your own first. :)

Comment: @Prateek.Naik : people who might have downvoted your question might probable are not finding what you have tried on your own for a very basic sample of execution.